# Cómo puedo hacer la unión y organización entre dos arreglos en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo el `arreglo1 = [3, 5, 1]` y el `arreglo2 = [ 2, 6, 4]`.

Cómo los puedo combinar para que queden en un solo arreglo ordenado?, es decir, que puedo codear para que el arreglo resultante quede como `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` ?

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Answer (score 5):

Puedes primero concatenar dos **arrays** y después aplicas la función de ordenamiento **[sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort).**

```js
var array1 = [3, 1, 4]; 
var array2 = [2, 6, 5]; 

var arrayUnion = array1.concat(array2) //Lo Concatena
arrayUnion = arrayUnion.sort(); //Lo Ordena

console.log(arrayUnion)
```

Comment: SI haces click en el boton Ejecutar, podras ver el console.log

Comment: También podría hacer un `console.log(([ ...array1, ...array2 ]).sort())`